# PHP Render/Redirect AJAX Call

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, rendering

I am working on a PHP application and missing some of the functionality that Rails has. I currently have an AJAX form that when submitted accesses my_page_save_ajax.php. After I process the form and save it, I would like to redirect the AJAX call to either my_page_show_ajax.php if successful or back to my_page_edit_ajax.php if an error occurred.

I have thought about using an `include my_page_..._ajax.php`, but I have always had problems with the file paths and PHP not knowing what to render. Not to mention, both of those files `include utilities.php` and I'm afraid there might be conflicts. I guess I could use `include_once` but it seems like there might be a more elegant solution.

How can I process the form and return the output of another PHP page?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Edited my question to be more correct for what I am attempting to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you redirect the AJAX response, it won't actually redirect the user's browser anywhere. It will simply affect what data comes back through the AJAX call. This may be a good instance to simply not use AJAX, since it sounds like the user may go on only one of two paths.

If you still want to redirect the user, you could send back a javascript snippet which redirects the user via setting window.location

Comment: Actually, I specifically don't want to redirect the user. I just want to redirect the AJAX response so that different data is sent back. How would I redirect the AJAX response using PHP?

Comment: Okay...it looks like using `header('Location: my_page_new_ajax.php')` does the trick. Thanks for your help!